# Django not creating tables for an installed app

Tags: django, django-syncdb

My django site was functioning before I installed Lion and had to reinstall everything related to development.  Since then, I have deleted and recreated my database, but one of my two installed apps is being ignored in syncdb.  Those tables are not present in my database.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435523/manage-py-syncdb-doesnt-add-tables-for-some-models) suggested there might be an import error.  I can import the app in question using manage.py shell, so I don't think that's it.

Both apps are definitely installed (verified by debug toolbar). Any other suggestions?  I'm relatively new to Django, having been mostly an iOS developer for the past couple of years.

Comment: Are you sure you included them in the INSTALLED_APPS list in your settings.py?

Comment: syncdb output would be nice too

Comment: They are absolutely 100% positively both in my INSTALLED_APPS list in my settings.py, debug toolbar says so too.

Comment: Absolutely in INSATLLED_APPS.

Comment: ah -- my second installed app has a heirarchy, and that was causing the problem.  Models were inside a folder in the app rather than being in the app itself.  Don't know why it worked before...I switched from postgresql back to sqlite3 after the lion install, but I doubt that could be it. Nothing else has changed....

Comment: Do you use south for migrating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#app-label

> If a model exists outside of the standard models.py (for instance, if the app’s models are in submodules of myapp.models), the model must define which app it is part of.

What it doesn't mention is that they also have to be imported somewhere during the model registration phase.